# Azure QNA Maker HTTP POST

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

How do I send a request in the form of json format and get back an answer?

I tried sending a post request but I keep getting "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Is there a format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See here for sample code to post requests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/csharp

Answer (score 0):

QnA Maker is now GA (until recently it was in preview)

**PREVIEW Version**
POST request to your end-point and you need to set two header parameters in the request

endpoint looks like 
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/SOME_ID_STRING/generateAnswer

```
Content-Type=application/json 

Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
```

**GA Version**

You will first spin the resource in regular portal and go to qnamaker.ai site to create a KB)
endpoint looks like https://YOUR_END_POINT.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/SOME_ID_AFTER_PUBLISHING_KB/generateAnswer
header parameters changed

```
Content-Type=application/json

Authorization=EndpointKey <YOUR_AUTH_KEY>
```

Comment: Thank you sir.Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353205/qnamaker-with-luis