# qnamaker with LUIS

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I'm exploring the microsoft services.

LUIS caught my attention.
Would it be beneficial to add it to a QNAmaker bot?

The bot basically answers questions as accurately as possible, nothing else, just pure answer from knowledgebase.

Do I even need to add LUIS?

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need LUIS to have QnA maker answer questions. You might add LUIS as the app grows to do more than just a faq style interaction.

Answer (score 0):

By itself, if all you want is for the bot to answer questions, then this is sufficient. However, even still it is helpful to pre-emptively tell users what your bot can actually do, so I would also like to suggest adding a pro-active message which actually informs your user of what your bot can actually do, i.e have the bot say something like: "Hi! I'm -A Bot-, you can ask me questions and I'll do my best to answer!"

If you are interested in looking at a c# implementation of LUIS with QnA here is a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/blog-samples/CSharp/Luis-Scorable-QnA)